# What is the use case for blocks in template engines?

Tags: templates, code-layout

Most template engines have two ways to refer to other templates:

1. Inheritance with blocks (child template inherits from parent template and fills one or more blocks)
2. Includes (parent template includes child template).

Coming from vanilla PHP require/include and from component based JavaScript frameworks, I never really understood what I need those template blocks for. In JavaScript frameworks like Vue, React, Svelte etc. data flows from top down and child components do not know about their parents.

Today I read some template engine tutorials again about creating a skeleton layout template and then inherit from it, but it just goes against everything I learned. Why in the world would a child template know about multiple blocks existing in the parent template. For me that goes completely against separation of concerns. A child template should know about itself and nothing more. Why would I want to include that dependency to the parent template?

I think whenever I use a block in a parent template, I would be better off to include a child template (like a component) based on a variable. If I have 3 different blocks, then I should include 3 different child components. One child component should never be responsible for multiple blocks of a parent template.

This works great for JavaScript frameworks and the most complex applications are based on it, so it definitely works without template blocks.

Why do you still use template blocks? Is it just because you know it like that or is it just an alternative way of designing or do you really have a use case that you think is easier to solve with blocks than with includes?

Comment: Say you're writing the most basic of webpages. You have a title, and some content. The title goes in the header, in a different section of an HTML document as the content. Your template will cover all formatting, so it'll have two blocks the actual page needs to provide info for.

Comment: @whatsisname Let's say you have 5 pages with a title and content. Then you have to create 1 parent template and 5 child templates. In your code you still have to decide which template to load based on a condition. Why not include the correct template, based on that condition in the template and always load the same parent template in your code? Or better, just set the title directly. You really do not need a template for something simple as a title. Then, if multiple child templates share the same title and you want to change it, you have to change it only in the parent and not in each child.

Comment: Blocks aren't necessary in most cases, you can use conditionals instead (where React components would likely use a router). But they're super useful for themes, letting users adjust some blocks in the theme without changing the parent theme templates. The corresponding React pattern would be to use "render props" or to pass components as props to another component, e.g. `MyCustomLayout = () => <Layout footer={MyCustomFooter}>`.

Comment: @amon How are blocks in your example different to includes? I can also dynamically include a child template (based on a variable) and then edit that child template without changing the parent theme template.

Comment: @Toxiro Sure, an include to a dynamically computed filename achieves the same general purpose. But here the exact featureset matters. E.g. in Jinja, blocks offer better scoping than includes, and resolving filenames from runtime data can be a security weakness. Other engines like Go's text-template don't allow variables to influence which template is called, whereas Liquid only has includes and no blocks/inheritance. But all of this is fine, it is normal for there to be multiple ways to achieve the same goal.